# sql how set default value boolean of a new column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to set the default value of a new column from an already existed table to boolean False.

In my case, it should be like this :

```
id    car      boolean

1     Peugeot  false
2     Ford     false
3     Ferrari  false
...
```

I've tried this :

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicules
ADD operate boolean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `default <value>` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicules
ADD operate boolean default true
```